# Python task - Grid of Asterisks

Tags: python

Write a program to prompt the user to enter 2 numbers: one for number of columns and one for number of rows and outputs a grid of asterisks with the specified number of rows and columns 
 Hint: You will need to use one loop nested inside another. 
 For example, given width = 3 and height = 4, the program should output the following grid:

```
 * * * 
 * * *
 * * *
 * * *
```

This is what I have so far:

```
width = int(input("Please enter a width for your grid:"))

rows = int(input("Please enter the amount of rows in your grid:"))

for width in range (5,0,-1):

print(width * ' ' + (5 - width) * '*')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a snippet:

```
w = 5
h = 4
for i in range(h):
    print ' *' * w + ' '
```

output:

```
 * * * * * 
 * * * * * 
 * * * * * 
 * * * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're being asked to use nested loops, you'll want to `print` asterisks separated by spaces in the inner loop, and move to the next line at the end of that loop:

```
for x in range(rows):
    for y in range(width):
        print('*',end = ' ')
    print()
```